# Why is the right padding ignored near scroll bar and how to fix this in my case?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.outer {
  padding: 50px;
}

.inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">qwerty</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as I am concerned, inline-block display isn't convenient, cause I want to center my inner div.

Answer (score 1):

it's break down the right padding because right and left padding of outer div is 50+50=100px and your inner div width is 500px so when window screen is less then  600px outer div right padding break down and inner div width 500px takes its fixed width. 
In this case you can use [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) or [max-width  method](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp). you also set width to  50% or 100% no media query no max-width need to be set.

**Here is solution with max-width method**

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.outer {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner {
   max-width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner"> 
   <div class="content">qwerty</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this at the top of your style-sheet:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

also you should use

```
margin: 0 auto
```

for your inner div to center horizontally

Answer (score 0):

```
 Change the width 
<div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">qwerty</div>
      </div>
    </div>

.outer {
  padding: 50px;
 border:1px solid red;

}

.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin:0 auto
}
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/bpyfckn6/

Answer (score 0):

Your .inner has a `width:500px` so it won't be less than that. To fix your issue:

```
.inner {
width: 100%;
max-width:500px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4sk4bqxh/